# guys any possible refractory code for the above code

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, refactoring

Guys I want to modify this if or block so dynamically it divide the value x based on what or condition got executed.

```
    public boolean isUgly(int n) {
        boolean isUgly=true;
        while(n>0)
        {
            if(n%2==0||n%3==0||n%5==0)
            {
                n = n/x //<-------- here i want x should be based on the if condition where or is true
            }
            else {
                isUgly=false;
                break;
            }
        }
    return isUgly;
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. If `n/2 == 0`, `n` is probably 0. Why do you still want to divide it further?

Comment: oops sorry, I made a mistake..

Comment: now I corrected it,

Comment: Okay, now it makes a little more sense. However, it is still unclear what you want `x` to be when multiple conditions are fulfilled. For example, what should happen when `x` is 15, or 30?

Comment: I want to make it dynamic, if say in or condition 2 get executed then x =2 ; else 3 then x=3 ...like that

Comment: Writing `isUgly=false; break;` is ugly, just write `return false;` instead.

Comment: You can't make it dynamic.  Java doesn't support that.

Comment: you can write a method `int getBiggestDevisitor(int n)`, but this will be slow

Comment: @Ofek What is a "devisitor"?

Comment: I meant divisor*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You looking for something like this?

```java
public static boolean isUgly(int n) {
    final int[] uglyPrimes = {2, 3, 5};
    boolean isUgly = true;
    while (n > 1 && isUgly) {
        isUgly = false;
        for (int x : uglyPrimes) {
            if (n % x == 0) {
                n = n / x;
                isUgly = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return isUgly;
}
```

---

Of course, I would just implement it like this:

```java
public static boolean isUgly(int n) {
    while (n > 1 && n % 2 == 0)
        n /= 2;
    while (n > 1 && n % 3 == 0)
        n /= 3;
    while (n > 1 && n % 5 == 0)
        n /= 5;
    return (n <= 1);
}
```

Or this:

```java
public static boolean isUgly(int n) {
    for (int x : new int[] { 2, 3, 5 })
        while (n > 1 && n % x == 0)
            n /= x;
    return (n <= 1);
}
```

---

All 3 solutions really should have the following added to the beginning of the method, but that's outside the scope of the challenge:

```java
if (n <= 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value: " + n);
```

Comment: yo man! but here time complexity will be the problem.. but good try! **APPRECIATE

Comment: @mainhoonlucky Why would time complexity be a problem? It hasn't changed.

Comment: I saw two loops, that is nested.

Comment: @mainhoonlucky So? Number of loops doesn't by itself define complexity. You can write code with 3 nested loops and still only have _O(n)_. You can also write a single loop but end up with _O(n^3)_. The code for all 3 solutions in this answer is _O(log n)_.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, in this way you can divide `n` depending on the condition, but this method will always return `false` as in any case, it will execute the **else statement** for sure. What is your goal?

```
public boolean isUgly(int n) 
    {
        boolean isUgly=true;
        while(n>0)
        {
            if(n%2==0)
            {
                n = n/2;
            }
            else if(n%3==0)
            {
                n = n/3;
            }
            else if(n%5==0)
            {
                n = n/5;
            }
            else 
            {
                isUgly=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isUgly;
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want floating point numbers? Besides, that change made the code no longer compile. Up-vote changed to down-vote. So sad, ruining a good answer like that.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that the parameter is integer type, I thought about missing values for integer division and so I suggested that. Thanks for pointing out the error due to my overthinking on this point :p reverted changes